# What does "lay on the charm" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english, phrases

I've come across the expression in the 8th episode of the 3rd season of *The Office*. Here it is:

> Andy: Am I trying to get under his skin?  Y-y-yes, because the angrier
> he gets, the more marginalized he becomes.  Meanwhile, Andy Bernard is
> out there...  ...**laying on the charm**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [pour on the charm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pour%20on), you intentionally behave in a nice and polite way to make people like you or to impress them.

I think what Andy said is an alternative (possibly, American) to this phrase.

While Dwight is running around all "angry and marginalised", Andy is enjoying himself and appears more likable to all and to Michael in particular. What a great plan, haha!

Comment: I don't think _lay on the charm_ is particularly American. _Laying it on thick_ is a fairly common expression for flattering excessively or making a point very emphatically. Shakespeare coined the phrase _laid on with a trowel_, using mortar or plaster as a metaphor.